# How can I determine if a CD is marked as bootable?

Tags: windows-xp, compact-disc, bootable-media

I am trying to install Windows XP on a old laptop (Compaq Presario 700) with a stored verion of XP that I burned to an ISO.

The copy of XP is legitimate but it won't boot to it. I am able to boot to the Crap Recover CD that is basically just DOS, and to a copy of "Ultimate Boot CD v5" that I downloaded and created from the same computer and burner that the XP cd was made from.

Everything boots except for this XP CD. Is there a way to tell if it's bootable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a tool like [UltraISO](http://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/). It will indicate that the CD is bootable.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it's not bootable but you could use IsoBuster or one of [many similar programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_image_software) to check the ISO file or the actual disk.

Comment: -1  show where it says so