# Boot Windows XP installation from CD

Tags: windows-xp, boot, iso-image, windows-installer, cd-burning

I am trying to format and install Windows XP on a Toshiba Satellite laptop, but I can't boot from the CD. When I go to the BIOS system, I check that the boot order is correct, first the CD and then the disc. I already tried in another laptop and it was the same. I have downloaded the XP ISO file from Microsoft's site and burned the ISO image to a CD with ImgBurn. If I try to run the CD, it runs without any problem. Could be something wrong with the burn process? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: if it doesnt boot on any laptop its probably the burn process.

Comment: Does any of the laptops have an option of selecting the boot device manually (not in the bios, but during the bios sequence)? Often there is a menu for manual selection that you can open by pressing "F12" during the bios start sequence.

Comment: Does the bios offer `boot from lan` (pxe)?

Comment: Try the CD in another PC, see if it is bootable on that PC.

Comment: check if cd is bootable using program UltraIso suggested here http://superuser.com/questions/129437/how-can-i-determine-if-a-cd-is-marked-as-bootable

Answer (score 0):

The CD is probably not burned as bootable correctly.  [Did you follow this procedure?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVZMvGZjOWA)

The Youtube link above shows how you need a "floppy disk image" in conjuction with the "Bootable Disc" option in order to create a booting CD.