# How to know if a DVD or CD is bootable?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bartpe

I have been using winiso to check some disks for bootability but now I don't trust it.  It reported BartPE as non bootable but it booted on a broken machine for me.

The machine is an old Acer Aspire.  All  hard drives disconnected. So the disk had booted, seems to me.  Same with a RAM diagnostic disk. Running at this moment.   WinISO said that was nonboot, too.

I would like some other way to test disks. Anyone know of one?

Comment: i'm not sure how to check but just thought i'd point out that years ago winiso had an issue with bootable cds and dvds, it didn't keep the bootable aspect. This sounds like a different bug but still an issue related to 'bootability'!

Comment: there is ultra iso but it seems it's not free though there is a free trial http://superuser.com/questions/129437/how-can-i-determine-if-a-cd-is-marked-as-bootable  Notice it says 'bootable'  see  answer from sathya http://superuser.com/questions/129437/how-can-i-determine-if-a-cd-is-marked-as-bootable  so I guess your q is probably a duplicate q too

Comment: I'd personally just test it. This can be done by mounting the iso or cd through VirtaulBox and attempt to boot from it,